# How to work out covariance using the expected value of x,y and xy

Tags: probability, distributions

> Cov(x,y) if e(x) = 2.60 and e(y) = 2.35 and e(xy) = 7.06

i'm confused because all i know is
$$cov(x,y) = \text{correlation of xy}*sqrt(x)*sqrt(y) $$

Comment: You can find many formulas by searching our site for [covariance definition](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=covariance+definition).  I have pointed to one such post; it was the first one found in my search.

Comment: So should i expand cov(x,y) = E((x-e(x))(y-e(y))) ?